# Javascript ADO recordset open method not working. Parametrized queries

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ms-access, ado

I am creating a web page and have some javascript code to insert some information from the webpage to MS access database.
I am using ADO connections and record set but I am having a problem with the open method.

This is a snippet of the code I am having trouble with

```
var name =document.StatusReports.empname.value;
var query = "Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName =" + name;

    alert(query);

    if(adoRS.Open(query, adoConn, 1, 3));
```

Name is just a variable that will hold the value of a text box. (this works)
if I use alert(query) everything displays nicely: `Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName = kevin`
As if the concatenation worked fine.
But then If I try to open the connection with that query I get this error:

```
SCRIPT3600: No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

As if it didn't recognize the concatenation.

NOTE: IT works wihtout the concatenation. For example if I hardcode a value:

```
 var query = "Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName = kevin";
```

But that is not the purpose of course.

UPDATE: I think the problem is that the query is not parametrized. I remember in Java this happened to me but I parametrized ther query and I would be done.
Not sure how to paramterize queries using javascript

Comment: The search string should be in quotes.  Try:  `var query = "Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName ='" + name + "'"`.

Comment: That worked! If you want to put it as an answer so I can checmark it go ahead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will produce an error in Access, because it's trying to compare two field names:  "EmployeeName" and "kevin":

```
Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName = kevin
```

The following query should *not* produce an error, because it's comparing "EmployeeName" against a string *value* of "kevin":

```
Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName = 'kevin'
```

Put the search string `name` in quotes like this:

```
var query = "Select * From reportForm Where EmployeeName ='" + name + "'";
```